# Python -- web scraping -- "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Tags: python, python-3.x

***python***
***web scraping*** here, i have tried to get the content from website. but it's show type error

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response1 = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=cycle+for+men+27.5+inch&as=on&as- show=on&otracker=AS_Query_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_14_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_Query_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_14_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=HISTORY&suggestionId=cycle+for+men+27.5+inch&requestId=8684731e-89e9-4c19-9f4f- `enter code here`dd8ac2211eb1')
parsed_content1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.read(),"html.parser")
for cycle in parsed_content1.findall('a', {"class": "s1Q9rs"}):
    print(cycle.text)
```

Comment: Please post the error stack detail, especially the related line number. It's very useful for figuring out what's going wrong in your code.

Comment: what is the `url`. The one in your code is not right.

Comment: 1. The provided URL seems to be invalid, also if the Url contains single quotes then enclose the url within double quotes. 2.   parsed_content1.findall('a', {"class": "s1Q9rs"}) is incorrect, instead use    parsed_content.find_all('a', class_= "s1Q9rs").

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this:

```
import time
from urllib import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = #your url
parser = #your parser

data = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, parser)

#then you can search what you want
```

Comment: yes it had because is the basic metod to get a page source and it doesn't rise the error of the below code